# Uniform distribution over an hyper-ellipsoid

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, covariance

Let $\mathbf{X} \in \bf{R}^p$ be a random vector whose elements are uniformly distributed over the hyper-ellipsoid $x^TAx<1$, (where $A$ is a positive-definite matrix).  Is it possible to compute the covariance matrix of $\mathbf{X}$, and would it have any relation to $A$?

Answer (score 0):

The error covariance matrix is
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{p+2} A^{-1}.
\end{equation}

Comment: A statement of _why_ would help the OP and other readers at the OP's level.